# Cannot launch Settings on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: settings, gnome-control-center

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

or

```
$ killall gnome-control-center
```

or

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel ''
```

but they didn't work!

Comment: Just to eliminate a problem with your local account, create a new account... called Guest, or Test, whatever. Then log into that new account and try settings. If it works, let me know and I'll give you further steps. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema It says: 
natavews@veasnawt:~$ gnome-control-center
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-control-center:1056): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 03:16:55.727: gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-control-center:1056): Gtk-WARNING **: 03:16:55.727: cannot open display:

Comment: In which account did you get this error?

Comment: @heynnema New account that I've just created earlier.

Comment: That tells us that the problem is systemic, not local to your regular account. Are you having any other problems with this installation?

Comment: Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: Does `Software Updater` show any required updates?

Comment: What video hardware/software & version are you running?

Comment: @heynnema No, Software Updater is not showing any required updates, I am using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q, Version: REV:1.0

I'm not sure if I answered your question. I don't know what they really are.

Comment: Did you do the `fsck`? To find out the version number of the Nvidia driver, try `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep -i ii`. It'll probably look like 3xx.xx.

Comment: status please...

Comment: Newest Nvidia driver is version 440.44, released 12/11/19, at https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: status please...